# VIM: Incorrect cursor position

Tags: vim

Recently I have been facing a problem of incorrect display of cursor position in vim editor. The cursor is not displaying at the position it is actually pointing. It is displayed before its apparent position. The position differs according to the level of indentation. It goes like this:

(*) denotes the position of cursor displayed when pointing to the extreme end.

1. No indentation:

   `def example():*`

Remark: normal.

2. First indentation:

   `def example():
       if i is True:*`

Remark: normal

3. Second indentation:

   `def example():
       if i is True:
           print "True*"`

Remark: 1 position behind

4. Third indentation:

   `def example():
       if i is True:
           print "True"
           if j is True:
              print "j is Tru*e"`

Remark: 2 position behind.

...And so on.
The measure of error increases as the number of indentation level increases.

What is the cause of this issue? How do I fix it?

Comment: How are you indenting? In what mode, etc.

Comment: Means? 1Tab = 4spaces

Comment: Are you using `>>` to indent in edit mode? Ctrl-T in insert mode? There are many ways to do indenting. Do you have any plug-ins that you use? etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect cursor position"? What keys did you press, and what expectations did you have?

Comment: @AIG I use syntastic. The problem occure after I installed NERDtree and (https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine). Nothing happened before.

Comment: @Jeff The cursor is not displaying at the position it is actually pointing. It is displayed before the position it is pointing, the position differs according to the level of indentation. I pressed tab for indentation. I expect to display the cursor where it is actually pointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a reported bug with the indentLine plugin you are using. See https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine/issues/94

One suggested fix is to put this in your vimrc

```
let g:indentLine_noConcealCursor=1
```

Comment: Thanks...The bug is fixed using the snippet. I don't feel comfortable using this indentLine plug-in. Would you suggest any plug-in analogous to indentLine?

Comment: You're welcome.  If this fixed your answer, go ahead and mark it "accepted".  As far as recommendations for a replacement, I have not used any plugins like that. The closest thing I use like it is code folding.  You can see some of that here: http://smartic.us/2009/04/06/code-folding-in-vim/ , but that probably isn't what you are looking for

Comment: You save my day. But it's weird that I didn't have `indentLine` plug installed when this bug occurs. After installing this plug, I uses this snippet to solve my problem. So in my case, it seems the wrong position is not caused by this plugin?